# start IAP tunnel programmatically with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

i am trying to connect to a VM through a IAP tunnel, and i need to first open the tunnel
I am able to do it with gcloud CLI, however i would like to do it through a python script, possibly without having to resort to run bash command with the subprocess library

Does anybody know if there is a python library that allows me to open a IAP tunnel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud client libraries currently don't provide support for IAP TCP tunneling. [IAP Desktop includes an OSS implementation for IAP TCP tunneling](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-desktop/tree/master/sources/Google.Solutions.IapTunneling), but it's C#.

So running `gcloud` might be your best bet.